Jenkins build with parameters use parameters from pipeline
I have probably simple issue. I look online but for now I didn't found answer (will carry on searching), so maybe there someone will be able to help.
I have a pipeline with parameters. I set them in my jenkinsfile and also on Jenkins.
But on new branch I want to add/remove some parameters. Is there a way that Jenkins will take them from jenkinsfile? or I have to each time change them also on Jenkins?
Currently I updating Jenkins but would like to avoid it in case someone else build job using default branch.

Jenkins can't know what the parameters for a job will be before it pulls the branch and checks the param list. Even so, it will only take effect from the next build onwards. You can instead just have all the parameters prepared but set them to optional so that you don't have to add/remove them for every build.

The lazy way is to only set your parameters in your Jenkinsfile. Do not set in Jenkins web interface. (Something will auto-populate into Jenkins, but ignore this.) When you switch to a new branch with different parameters, run a build just long enough for it to pull from SCM. Then abort the build. Then run again. The second run will have the correct parameters.
